# Android binding library: Type or namespace not found

Tags: android, xamarin, binding

I developed a Android Binding Library to bind a printer Android AAR file (The AAR has its build action set to LibraryProjectZip), and the project is compiled using Android 7.1, using class-parse android class parser, and AndroidCodeGen Target: XAJavaInterop1. ***I can provide the simple Project in order to have full access to the code and library***.

But I have the following error: 'The type or namespace 'ILibrary' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Sun.Jna' at Com.Sun.Jna.Native.cs. So I decided to check at the Android library using a decompiler and here is what I found:

- The AAR file contains an interface 'Library' (not ILibrary), and the Native.class file contains a method whose signature is the following and is the source of the error and which requires a Library object as input

  `public static Library synchronizeLibrary(final Library library){...}`
- The C# generated code contains a Com.Sun.Jna.ILibrary.cs file which contains a public abstract class 'Library':

  `[Register ("com/sun/jna/Library", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)] public abstract class Library : Java.Lang.Object {...}`

  but the generated Native.cs file has the counterpart method SynchronizeLibrary :

  `// Metadata.xml XPath method reference:  [Register ("synchronizedLibrary", "(Lcom/sun/jna/Library;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;", "")] public static unsafe global::Com.Sun.Jna.ILibrary SynchronizedLibrary(global::Com.Sun.Jna.ILibrary library) {...}`

I do not understand why the C# generated method SynchronizedLibrary demands an ILibrary and not the Library.

I tried to modify the Metadata.xml file to rename the class Library to ILibrary but with no success. Moreover I have a warning saying that:

```
class-parse: warning: could not load .jar entry 'libjnidispatch.jnilib': System.Argument.OutOfRangeException,
```

I tried to change the name of the interface from Library to ILibrary using `<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.sun.jna']/class[@name='Library']" name="managedName">ILibrary</attr>` but the definition of the interface does not change. It is strange that I have a reference path for the members of the interface but not the interface itself

```
[Register ("com/sun/jna/Library", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]
    public abstract class Library : Java.Lang.Object {

        internal Library ()
        {
        }

        // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.sun.jna']/interface[@name='Library']/field[@name='OPTION_ALLOW_OBJECTS']"
        [Register ("OPTION_ALLOW_OBJECTS")]
        public const string OptionAllowObjects = (string) "allow-objects";,
```

and I do not know if it is related to the prior problem.

Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the way to correct the error by modifying the name of the interfaces by adding the following lines to the Metadata file:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.sun.jna']/interface[@name='Library']" name="name">ILibrary</attr>
```

But now I have errors telling me that JNIENv does not contain method like NewString. And I am wondering if it is related to the warning i have telling me that It cannot load .jar entry libjnidispatch.jnilib

Any ideas, thanks